# Can't link to fftw library using visual C++ express on windows 64 bit

Tags: windows, visual-c++, fftw

I'm trying to link to the fftw library using visual c++ express, but am getting linker errors when I try to compile. I generated the lib files as the site (http://fftw.org/install/windows.html) explains by creating  .lib "import libraries" using the lib.exe program.

I added the .lib files to "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib", and fftw3.h to "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include". I then put the dll files in "Windows/system32" folder. I linked the libraries by adding them (libfftw3f-3.lib, libfftw3-3.lib, libfftw3l-3.lib) to additional dependencies on the linker/input preferences. When I try to compile I get the following errors:

```
    process_wav.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftwf_destroy_plan referenced in function _main
    process_wav.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d referenced in function _main
```

I searched on stack overflow but most of the answers explain that the libraries need to be added to additional dependencies to be found. When I put /verbose:lib on command line options I get the following:

```
    f
    fdf

1>Linking...
1>Searching libraries
1>    Searching libfftw3f-3.lib:
1>    Searching libfftw3-3.lib:
1>    Searching libfftw3l-3.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile-win32-bin-1.1.7\libsndfile-1.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\user32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\winspool.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\shell32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\ole32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\uuid.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\MSVCRTD.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\msvcprtd.lib:
1>    Searching libfftw3f-3.lib:
1>    Searching libfftw3-3.lib:
1>    Searching libfftw3l-3.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile-win32-bin-1.1.7\libsndfile-1.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\user32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\winspool.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\shell32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\ole32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\uuid.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\MSVCRTD.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\msvcprtd.lib:
1>    Searching libfftw3f-3.lib:
1>    Searching libfftw3-3.lib:
1>    Searching libfftw3l-3.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile-win32-bin-1.1.7\libsndfile-1.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>    Searching F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>Finished searching libraries
```

It seems to find the libraries but does not know who to find the function names in them. I got the code from a website which also uses this library, interestingly the function names do not appear in "fftw3.h" but I don't think this is the cause of the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not sure where to turn now.

Thanks.

Comment: You must have edited the fftw3.h header file so that __declspec(dllimport) was used.  The .h file suggest to do so, after the "annoying Windows syntax" comment.  That isn't actually the right thing to do, the precompiled DLLs don't export the __imp versions of the entrypoints.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Hans. Sorry for the late reply, I tried removing __declspec(dllimport) and ended up getting a lot of missing type specifier errors. I tried using the 32 bit library as suggested below and will go with this for the moment. I'm not sure why it couldn't find the function names when I used the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 3):

The following steps work for me in Visual Studio 2008 ( from http://itkcorner.blogspot.com/2012/01/inclusion-de-fftw-en-visual-studio-2008.html );

1. Download the file “fftw-3.3dll32.zip from fftw org website (http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html)
2. In order to link to these .dll files from Visual C++, you need to create .lib "import libraries" for them, and can do so with the "lib" command that comes with VC++.  In particular, run:
    lib /def:libfftw3-3.def

In “Tools > Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt” without opening any project, just Visual. Once you are in the console, you go with the ‘cd’ command to the root where the folder is placed and once there you run the three lines above, and then the ‘lib files are created.

1. Copy the folder where the libs are created and then copy it inside the project folder where we want to use it and rename the folder to “FFTW_LIBS”. In this folder the necessary files are the ones that have the ‘*.dll’ , ‘*.lib’ and the ‘fftw3.h’.
2. Inclusion of the libs in the project: “Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Entry > Additional dependencies” and then we include the three new libs files:

libfftw3-3.lib

1. Inclusion of the path where the libs are:
   a.  “Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional libs directory” , and there we write “./FFTW_LIBS”.
   b.  “Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Depuration > Environment” , and there we write “./FFTW_LIBS”.
2. Inclusion of the path where the ‘.dll’ file is. In “Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Depuration > Environment”. In the variable ‘enviroment’ we have to specify where the file ‘libfftw3-3.dll’ and we write “PATH = .\FFTW_LIBS”
   After all of this steps, you just have to add “ #include fftw3.h” and use the fftw functions!

Comment: Thanks Antonio, I tried this using the 32 bit version of the library and it worked fine. I'm not sure what went wrong when I tried the 64 bit version, but I'll go with this for now.

Answer (score 1):

I will introduce a slight modification to Antonio's steps:

Following worked for me on Windwos 10, Visual Studio 2017, 32bit application, x64 computer:

1. Download precompiled FFTW 3.3.5 Windows DLLs and extract the .zip file

   http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html
2. Open a developer cmd prompt for VS 2017 RC and go to the extracted
   folder
3. Run the lib application as follows to create the import libraries
   (.lib files) from the .dll libraries:

   ```
      lib /def:libfftw3-3.def

      lib /def:libfftw3f-3.def 

      lib /def:libfftw3l-3.def
   ```
4. Copy the following files into a new folder, call that new folder ***fftw_lib***:

   ```
          fftw3.h
          libfftw3-3.lib
          libfftw3f-3.lib
          libfftw3l-3.lib
          libfftw3-3.dll
          libfftw3f-3.dll
          libfftw3l-3.dll
   ```
5. Copy the "fftw_lib" folder into your project's folder
6. Tell the linker to include the .lib files in your project:

Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Entry > Additional dependencies =

```
       libfftw3-3.lib
       libfftw3f-3.lib
       libfftw3l-3.lib
```

7. Add the libraries' path to the Linker and Compiler:

Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional libs directory =

> C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MP_2\MP_2\fftw_lib

Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++> General > Additional include directories =

> C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MP_2\MP_2\fftw_lib

8. Include the path where the dll libs are:

Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Environment =

> PATH=C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MP_2\MP_2\fftw_lib

The End!

Comment: 2020, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, `Additional Dependencies` is under `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`. In the textbox, provide the full path to each .lib, separated by CRLF

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at runtime it will ask you for fftw dlls missing. 
 I got that case and simply putted 'em into system32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express on 64-bit Windows 7 and had the same issue as you while trying to build for x64. The problem was that I generated the `.lib` and `.exp` using `lib.exe` from "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013" shell. When I regenerated `.lib` and `.exp` from "VS2013 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt" shell, then all references were resolved.